# Magento Commerce - Paypal online refund

Tags: magento, paypal

Hi is a online refund for paypal possible in Magento version 1.8? I only get the offline option for an order or invoice.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Or login into magento admin panel click on orders tab view the order
you want to refund Click 'CreditMemo' button see [here]
http://www.ehow.com/how_10022187_refund-customer-magento.html

Credit Memo Location on an order: http://prntscr.com/8a1tru

Comment: This is no possible with paypal standard (all magento community). http://stackoverflow.com/q/30375154/2980105

Comment: not sure what you mean as you issue a refund via an invoice memo; there isn't a refund button in magento ce